# How can I apply a function to wysihtml5 texteditor?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, function, wysihtml5

Like this my function is working fine:

```
 $(".textarea").on("change keyup paste", function (){
      console.log("something happens");
  });
```

But when I want to apply it to my wysihtml5 it does not work anymore..

```
$('.textarea').wysihtml5();
$(".textarea").on("change keyup paste", function (){
      console.log("something happens");
});
```

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/issues/217

Comment: also https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/wiki/Events. It seems there is a wysohtml5 change event and a paste event that you can use, but no keyup. There's some code that how to hook the keyup event using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution:

```
$('.textarea').wysihtml5({
       events: {
           load: function() {
               var some_wysi = $('.textarea').data('wysihtml5').editor;
               $(some_wysi.composer.element).bind('keyup', function(){ 
                     console.log("something happens");
               });
            }
       }
});
```